# Can't open some websites in python

Tags: python, python-requests, urllib

I can get `requests.get(web).content` of any website except one, `www.bundukhansweets.pk`.

```
import requests
web = "http://umararfeen.com"
req = requests.get(web).status_code
print req
```

Result: `200`

But when I try to open a website that has `www.` at the start it says `403` (Forbidden). I even tried `"http://www."+website` and `"www."+website`:

```
import requests
web = "http://bundukhansweets.pk"
print requests.get(web).status_code
```

Result: `403`

I even tried `urllib2` but failed.

Comment: Welcome to SO. have you tried any other websites with www. prefix?

Comment: yeah its my company's website it also have www. in start but i can get its content using "http://"+website :) 
But Not This One :')

Answer (score 1):

you are missing headers

## change

```
import requests
web = "http://bundukhansweets.pk"
hdr = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip,deflate,sdch',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive'
}
print requests.get(web, headers=hdr).status_code
```

this will work

Comment: Thanks Bro You're A Life Saviour <3 :)